# Realtek Card Reader 5286 in Asus X551MA Laptop/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, realtek

looking for suggestions on how to address an issue with my SD card reader. I first tried to see if updating the kernel to 3.16 would be enough, and it didn't. Next, I found instructions to modify kernel module here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1250605

The instruction from exemat in that link worked, but I am now getting an error on boot: "Bad LUN" and "Bad target number". I can boot to desktop, and files from the card can be read and copied, but I'm concerned that this might have some effect I'm not clear on. Do I have a reason to be concerned?

I'm pasting relevant info, and if I missed including something, please let me know. Thanks.

`uname -a`

```
Linux serge-X551MA 3.16.0-031600-lowlatency #201408031935 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 3 23:44:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Snips from `dmesg`:

```
[    0.911514] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.911519] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.915383] ahci 0000:00:13.0: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 2 ports 3 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
[    0.915391] ahci 0000:00:13.0: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo pio slum part deso sadm apst 
[    0.917679] scsi0 : ahci
[    0.918325] scsi1 : ahci

[    1.394970] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8E1    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.427965] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.427969] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.428169] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.428336] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    1.480440]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7
[    1.482134] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk

[   12.890518] rts_bpp: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   12.891153] Initializing Realtek PCIE storage driver...
[   12.891186] --- 11:24:27 ---
[   12.891395] Resource length: 0x10000
[   12.891414] Original address: 0xd0600000, remapped address: 0xffffc90010a80000
[   12.891489] pci->irq = 16
[   12.891492] rtsx_acquire_irq: chip->msi_en = 0, pci->irq = 16
[   12.938647] audit: type=1400 audit(1420321028.595:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=369 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.938658] audit: type=1400 audit(1420321028.595:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=369 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.938665] audit: type=1400 audit(1420321028.595:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=369 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.939497] audit: type=1400 audit(1420321028.595:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=369 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.939506] audit: type=1400 audit(1420321028.595:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=369 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.939933] audit: type=1400 audit(1420321028.596:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=369 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.949142] scsi2 : SCSI emulation for Realtek BarossaPlusPlus card reader
[   12.968240] rts_bpp: waiting for device to settle before scanning

[   13.968421] rts_bpp: device scan complete
[   13.968817] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- xD/SD/M.S.       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[   13.968969] Bad LUN (0:1)
[   13.969211] Bad target number (1:0)
[   13.969282] Bad target number (2:0)
[   13.969352] Bad target number (3:0)
[   13.969422] Bad target number (4:0)
[   13.969495] Bad target number (5:0)
[   13.969559] Bad target number (6:0)
[   13.969622] Bad target number (7:0)
[   13.970984] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   13.971454] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

`lspci -vvv`

```
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at d0600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable+ DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=0 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=0 offset=00000000
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
pcilib: sysfs_read_vpd: read failed: Connection timed out
        Not readable
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rts_bpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's been a few years since I've seen my last `bad lun`:  LUN = Logical Unit number on a SCSI chain.  So if all of your disks work fine, it's probably just a warning from the (experimental!) driver...

So the best you can do, is to set your brain's `[Ignore mode on]`

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: I suppose i'll recompile the module removing the bad target if i'm annoyed enough at the message.  Thanks! :)